# Laravel mailable not sending email

Tags: php, laravel, sendgrid, lumen

I am looking at sending a welcome email event via a Eloquent model using the `saved` event.

Everything seems to be working okay, up until actually sending the email. So I have added this at the top of the `User.php` model.

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
  'saved' => \App\Events\UserCreated::class
];
```

The `UserCreated.php` file just contains the basic boilerplate and assigning the user as well

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class UserCreated extends Event
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var User
     */
    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

Inside of the `EventServiceProvider.php` I am listening for then triggering the `SendWelcomeEmail.php` file.

```
 protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\UserCreated' => [
        'App\Listeners\SendWelcomeEmail'
    ]
];
```

`SendWelcomeEmail.php` looks like this...

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\UserCreated;
use App\Mail\WelcomeEmail;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendWelcomeEmail
{

    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  UserCreated  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserCreated $event)
    {
        $user = $event->user;

        Mail::to($user->email_address)->send(new WelcomeEmail($user));
    }
}
```

So far, I can do a `dd` inside of the `WelcomeEmail` class and I can see it display on screen, however the request completes, I get the response back and I get no error. However, the mail never actually sends to the user.

I am using SendGrid for this and I have followed everything exactly what they have put in, I cannot see any requests going into SendGrid and the request from my end is far to quick to actually send the email.

I have registered the mail config and the `MailServiceProvider` inside of `app.php` so I really don't know what it could be.

I also 100% know I am getting the correct user email address and dumping that out I am getting the correct input.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think your method call may be incorrect. According to the docs (for 5.1 anyways), you're supposed to wrap the `to()` function in a callback:

```
Mail::send('your.email.blade', $blade_variables, function($msg) use ($user) {
    $msg->to($user->email_address);
});
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#sending-mail for more info.